# Python 3.6 Dictionary. Get values from input at once

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm learning python 3.6 since a few weeks and stumbled in a [tutorial](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_dictionaries.php)
over the morse dictionary example.

There is a dictionary like:

```
morse = {
"A" : ".-", 
"B" : "-...", 
"C" : "-.-.", 
"D" : "-..",
...
...}
```

With my following code it's possible to enter one letter and get at stdout the matching morse code:

```
while 1:
    entry = input("letter: ")
    if entry in morse:
        result = morse[entry]
        print(result)
```

same behaviour with:

```
while 1:
    entry = input("letter: ")
    for i in entry:
    print(morse[entry])
```

What I want is to input complete words or sentences and get the morse code at stdout for each letter which was entered in one line

```
letter: ABC
.-,-...,-.-.
```

I thought the following might be work (but it does not..).

```
 #result is new dic for the resulting key:values
  result = {}
  while 1:
      entry = input("letter: ")
      if entry in morse:
          result = morse[entry]
          print(result)
      else:
          for i in entry:
              i = entry.split()
              print(morse[i])
```

which results in error, don't care if I input `AB` or `A B` (`.split()` the default separator is \w, I think)

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I also tried if I can get on with dict.get() or dict.update().
I think there must be a simple way to do this, or? ;) 
Is the goal to iterate the input?

I appreciate any help

Comment: You shouldn't need the split. If entry is a string, your for loop should loop through each character in the string one at a time setting i to that character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need the split or the if statement that you have. Check to see if this works for you:

```
while 1:
    entry = input("letters: ")
    for i in entry:
        if i in morse:
            print(morse[i])
```

If you want all of the letters for a loop on the same line you can append them to a list or add them to an empty string and then print that at the end of the loop like this:

```
while 1:
    result = ""
    entry = input("letters: ")
    for i in entry:
        if i in morse:
            result += morse[i]
    print(result)
```

Comment: Good enough but a lot of unnecessary code. Have a look at dict.get() function. :)

Comment: Hear hear.  This is close to the OP's code, but there are better ways to do this in Python for sure!

Comment: I agree that there are better ways of doing this, but since peep_durple stated that they are going through a tutorial, I wanted to make as few changes to their code as possible. No point in overloading them with stuff they haven't learned yet.

Comment: OP == "Original Poster" == peep_durple

Comment: @NendoTaka I agree. Thank you. For the moment your solution is good enough to continue learning. But I will look and understand each other solution here, too :)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> morse = {
... "A" : ".-", 
... "B" : "-...", 
... "C" : "-.-.", 
... "D" : "-.."}
>>> print(','.join(morse[x] for x in input() if x in morse))
AXBC
.-,-...,-.-.
```

(use `raw_input` in Python 2)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
morse = {
  "A" : ".-",
  "B" : "-...",
  "C" : "-.-.",
  "D" : "-.."
}

word = input("word:")

print(','.join(morse[letter] for letter in word if letter in morse))
```

By way of explanation, the code inside the `print` statement does the following:

1. Iterates over the input string
2. For any key
   that exists in `morse`, returns the matching value
3. Builds up all returned
   values into a list
4. Joins the list elements (morse characters) with
   commas

Comment: For the record, the `.join()` accepts a generator so you can remove the brackets `[]`inside join.

Comment: Right!  I forgot about that.  Awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Use [dict.get()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) which basically is: dict.get(value-by-key,value-if-not-found). The value if-not-found can be an empty string `""`

```
morse = {
"A" : ".-", 
"B" : "-...", 
"C" : "-.-.", 
"D" : "-.."}

myinp = "ABCA2"

print(','.join(morse.get(i,'') for i in myinp))
```

Returns:

```
'.-,-...,-.-.,.-,'
```

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that OP wanted the list elements comma-separated.

Comment: Nice.  Now you and I can hang out here in the also-rans... :)

Comment: dict.get(key[,default]) like @"Anton vBR" described is a very nice solution.